# Format ISO date in API response data

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, format, iso8601

How to format the date when inside {{item.Date}} 
I get a lot of rows and I don't know to format them all at once
I thought that setting the datatype in MySQL as Date would fix it but it apparently doesn't.
Thanks in advance!
What I get

```
2021-03-18T23:00:00.00Z
```

What I want

```
2021-03-15
```

MyCode

API

```
app.get('/schedetails/:schid', (_req, _res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query('Select * from ScheDetails where Schedule_ID = ?',[_req.params.schid], (err, rows, _fields) => {
        if (!err)
            _res.send(rows);
        else
            console.log(err);
    })
});
```

.ts file

```
getScheduleDetail(item){
    this.http.get("http://localhost:3000" +"/schedetails/"+ item).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
      this.schedetaildata = res;
    })
  }
```

html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of schedetaildata">
    <p>{{item.Weekday}}</p>
    <p>{{item.Time_start}}</p>
    <p>{{item.Time_finish}}</p>
    <p>{{item.Date}}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's a fairly simple operation to loop over rows and slice() the strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an ISO 8601 date string and since the positions are fixed, you know you only need the first 10 characters.

The simplest solution would be to use `substring()`.

Example:

```
{{ item.Date.substring(0, 10) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, Nathan! Do you know any way to remove the leading zeros from the date for example 2021-03-21 into 2021-3-15? I tried  .replace(/-0+/g, '-') , it doesn't work for me!

Comment: No problem :) What are you seeing when you use the `replace` that you posted? At first glance it seems as though it should work as you expect it to. `{{ item.Date.substring(0, 10).replace(/-0+/g, '-') }}`